# ol3-google-maps error: olgm is not defined

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, ol3-google-maps

I want to use Google Maps for Openlayers in my project. I try to integrate the maps with this: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps. But I can't get even the simplest example to work. The map doesn't load (blank space), and in the console I get "ReferenceError: olgm is not defined". This is the code I have:

```
    <script>
...code...
        var googleLayer = new olgm.layer.Google();
        var center = [-7908084, 6177492];
        var map = new ol.Map({
                interactions: olgm.interaction.defaults(),
            controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
                    overviewMapControl,
                    mousePositionControl,
                    new ol.control.ScaleLine()
            ]),
                layers: [googleLayer],
                target: 'map',
                view: new ol.View({
                  center: center,//[0, 0],
                  zoom: 2
                })
              });
              var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({map: map}); // map is the ol.Map instance
              olGM.activate();
...code...
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=MYKEYHERE"></script>
        <script src="js/ol3gm-debug.js"></script>
```

What can I possibly do wrong?

Comment: Put your script tag after "olg3m-debug.js" script tag.

Comment: Ok, this fixed the mistake, but I still get the blank map. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to check div id.

Comment: I have <div id="map" class="map"></div>
I have added iverted commas here: var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({map: 'map'});
Now I see a blank map with controls.

Comment: I think this is the same issue: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192253/map-gears-ol3-google-maps-not-showing-the-google-layer-even-after-adding-google
But the answer is inaswered :(

Comment: i created an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your script tag after "olg3m-debug.js" script tag.
You need to check div id.

And put your script inside document ready for use DOM after initialize.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your script goes here
});
```

Comment: I did all that but I still get the blank map. 
I tried to copy and run this example (http://mapgears.github.io/ol3-google-maps/examples/dist/examples/simple.html), but I still get the same result.

Comment: Would you please create a JSFiddle out of your example?  I'd be willing to  try to see what's wrong to help.

Comment: @AlexandreDubé create yours. I will help to you.

Comment: I'm confused.  I'm not the one reporting the problem, therefore I don't know how to reproduce this exactly.  Sorry about that.  I think @thebat93 should be the one creating his/her own example and anyone willing to help could go from there.

Comment: @AlexandreDubé Here you have it: http://jsfiddle.net/p3yL0qwv/1/.
Strangely enough it works now O_o.
I wrapped the map div in <section> tag and added this to the css style:
section #map {
  margin: 5px auto;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #CDD7EE;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 620px;
}.
I would appreciate it if someone told me why this thing matters.

Comment: The `<section>` element is irrelevant.  The div in which you want to draw the map has to have a size set for the map to be drawn.  The initialization in the `ready` method is important too.  Glad you could make it work.